# git rebase emergency sandbox commit without affecting another commit thats broken on stage

Tags: git

this may be a partially unique scenario here, but i want to rebase, and feel i might break the "stage" repo branch.

note, im the only developer, no worries about any other developers having these checkouts.

we have ticket 201, and we have the emergency ticket 407. 201 and 407(in that order) have ALREADY BEEN COMMITED, merged TO STAGE(branch), then pushed to stage.

Both of these tickets failed to pass QA on stage, so they both need fixes.  407 became an emergency fix. 201 is to wait until 407 has made its way up to production.  I  had to go back to sandbox(branch) and fix it. Its now fixed, and ready to commit.  201 needs to wait.  201 was commited before 407, and shows up on both sandbox logs and stage logs.

Im afraid if i rebase out 201 on sandbox temporarily (not really sure if this is the best way) to finalize the 407 fix, then when i go to merge then push to stage something unbeknownst will happen and the push(or merge) will complain with unbeknownst errors because of 201 (which was just rebased out on sandbox) getting in the way on stage.

Is there a way to rebase out (ticket 201) to make way for 407 to go through to stage?  what will happen to 201 which is already on stage?

Comment: negative vote, gotta love it. wtf do you want me to do to ask a question around here? this is why im hesitant to use SO, makes me look bad even though ive been developing for 20+ years.

Comment: There's really no reason to rebase anything here.  You only want to use it in select, specific cases, and when you're merging branches, that's *not* a good time for rebase.  If I understand you correctly, you claim that both 201 and 407 are in stage, right?  These commits happened one after the other, right?  Does 407 resolve the issues addressed in 201?  Is 201 (or 407) on its own branch?

Comment: yes both were on stage, yes commits happened one after the other, 407 doesnt resovle 201, they are two different issues, one took priorority over the other thats all.

Comment: Were the fixes on two different branches?  If so, I'd fix the issues on those branches and merge that into staging (or wherever) to be tested instead.  If they're not, then you could follow isim's advice below and simply create new commits to fix the broken checkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you have 2 feature branches which have been merged into your main branches in a particular order, and you're wondering if it will be OK to merge them again (with their additional commits added) in a different order. Is that right?

This should be absolutely fine, as long as they don't affect the same (or adjacent) lines of code, in which case you would of course run into conflicts (regardless of the order you merge them). However,if you want a cleaner history you could always reset your staging branch to the state it was in before merging either branch, and then merge them again (in any order).

If in doubt though, just make sure all the branches in your local clone are up to date with your authoritative remote, then if you do run into problems with any merges locally you can simply reset the affected branch(es) from the remote (which is effectively acting as a backup in this sense). You can also create local backups of the branches if you need to experiment without touching the originals, e.g

```
$ git checkout stage
$ git checkout -b stage_bak
```

You could even create another local clone of the entire repository if you like. However you do it, I've certainly found that the best way to really figure out what you can do with Git is to just try stuff, break it, reset it and try again.

Good luck!

Comment: they are not feature branches, they are the main branches.  i dont have any feature branches.  i have sandbox branch, stage branch and prod branch, each has its own remote destination respectively solely for a 3 stage QA process.  i do all work in sandbox, when its approved i push to stage using stage branch only, likewise for prod.    i wanted to reorder the commits so i could merge into stage all but 201, so that stage env wouldnt break for whatever reason.  i backed up before i made the OP.

Answer (score 2):

[Rewriting history](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) is tricky business. Personally, I will just try to [keep things simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (especially in the face of emergency), and commit those fixes as new commits, clearly marked with messages like *"Fix 407"* and *"Fix 201"*, respectively, and then merge them back into your `STAGING` branch. After all, how bad can these new commits be?

**If you really wanted to rewrite those previous commits...**

One way to go about it is to rollback to the commit **before** the original commit of ticket 201 **in both branches**. Since that commit is broken anyway, one may argue that it shouldn't remain on staging, left alone production. You can utilize either `git reset` or `git branch -f` like this:

```
git reset --soft commit_sha_of_201_parent
```

or

```
git branch -f staging_branch commit_sha_of_201_parent
git branch -f sandbox_branch commit_sha_of_201_parent
```

After the rollback, you may find [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) helpful in managing those (temporary) rollback uncommitted changes. Now you can fix your codes incrementally; first ticket 407, then ticket 201. Then eventually, they can be merged back into your `staging` branch.

As @Tony pointed out, you should make plans to clone/backup your stuff prior to this attempt.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the sugggestions, good advice.  the whole plan was to put 201 on the back burner and simply get it out the way so it didnt break my flow when i tried to push in a merged rebase to stage.

Comment: @BrianThomas Glad it helps. If you deemed this as an acceptable answer, please mark as accepted. Thanks!